# Equivalent of Lodash’s .maxBy in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, lodash, equivalent, external-dependencies, maxby

What is the JavaScript equivalent of Lodash’s .maxBy? I saw the code `_.maxBy(values, ...)` in a YouTube tutorial on minimax. I didn’t want to use any external dependencies, but when I googled my question, I couldn’t find anything that answered my question.

I do have a guess though - forEach except it also finds the maximum value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/aa18212085c52fc106d075319637b8729e0f179f/src/maxBy.ts#L20-L40), it's open source:

```
function maxBy(array, iteratee) {
    let result;
    if (array == null) {
        return result;
    }
    let computed;
    for (const value of array) {
        const current = iteratee(value);

        if (
            current != null &&
            (computed === undefined
                ? current === current && !isSymbol(current)
                : current > computed)
        ) {
            computed = current;
            result = value;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```